# Connecting PHP to MS Access

Tags: php, pdo, connection, ms-access-2010

I am currently struggling with connecting to a MS Access database using PHP. I have checked other relevant related posts trying to get aid but to no success. 
I am running windows 7 and attempting to connect to (.mdb database)

I have done the following trying to resolve this:

1. I have uncommented/enabled extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll in the php.ini
   file
2. I have re-installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe but still I am not getting any joy.
3. I have tried using the 32bit Windows ODBC connector (C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe) as well as the 64 bit version
   (C:\Windows\SysWOW64) version I am still not getting joy
4. I have also tried creating a custom drivers and including it in the code bust still no joy

Please see the code below:

```
try {
    $conn=new PDO('odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=$this->$dbName;Uid=$this->$Uid;Pwd=$this->$Upass');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I have created a custom driver called Microsoft Access:

```
try {
    $conn=new PDO('odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access};DBQ=$this->$dbName;Uid=$this->$Uid;Pwd=$this->$Upass');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I get this output all the time:

```
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Comment: And what is the error message you receive on failed attempts? Also, be sure `$dbname` points to a full path. MS Access like SQLite is a file-level database and not server-level.

Comment: I have tried using realpath() to try and target the overall path.

Comment: And again, what is the error/exception message php outputs. *No joy* is not helpful.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I modified my post. I get this error: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: What version of PHP are you running ([32-bit or 64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423848/checking-if-your-code-is-running-on-64-bit-php))? If 32-bit, try this driver: `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}`.

Comment: I have tried that driver you supplied but I still get the same error.  The Current PHP version: 5.4.3 and it is running on 32 bit.

Comment: See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712708/php-debugging-pdo-connection-to-access-database-accdb?rq=1