# ERROR in connecting pdo with odbc in php file not found

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

i am trying to connect the microsoft access database using pdo with odbc , i have mounted the files on network drive and i am trying to access them, but i am getting the following error :

> PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/info/new.mdb': file not found' .

here is my code :

```
$dbName = "/info/new.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$database = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$dbName;Dbq=/info/new;Uid=admin");
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the database file? i.e.`C:/my/path/to/info/new.mdb`? Also, does your database not have a password? :/

Comment: yeah . i am using the full path , it was on mounted drive and there is not password

Comment: Oh, you're also mixing odbc driver and dbq fields in pdo.`odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$dbName;Uid=admin;`

Comment: what i have to put in {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; ?

Comment: That's it, that string. You have to enable the odbc driver in your php.ini file (line should be `;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll`, just remove the semi-colon `;` at the beginning). If your database has a password you'll also need to append it to the PDO string with `Pwd=mysecretpassword` where `mysecretpassword` is your actual password.

Comment: i did that but again it is showing file not found

Comment: i am getting the error  'SQLSTATE[01000] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found' after using your answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712708/php-debugging-pdo-connection-to-access-database-accdb?rq=1