# Using XAMPP to access .accdb

Tags: php, ms-access, xampp

I am working on a web interface for a book database that my wife and I use. We have always kept it in .accdb and just used Access to make any changes but I would like to make it more accessible. I have a setup on XAMPP running that I use for other things so I made a folder there to test this with.

```
<?php
    //$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/db/Books.mdb";
    $dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "db/Books.accdb";

    if (!file_exists($dbName)){
        die("No database file.");
    }

    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    // $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Books ORDER BY author";
    $rs = $db->query($sql);
?>
```

If I convert the file to .mdb I can access it no problem but if I try it as .accdb and change the connection string to be for *.accdb or *.mdb, *.accdb it fails with:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1028 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. in C:\xampp\htdocs\_index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\_index.php(13): PDO->__construct('odbc:DRIVER={Mi...') #1 {main}
```

With XAMPP I was thinking it would be completely independent from the machine and use it's own driver but it's like the drive/connection is missing. I have ran phpinfo and have confirmed the ODBC connection is enabled but I can't find where to confirm what extensions it supports to make sure that's not the issue.

Comment: This may answer your question, but you may not like the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712708/php-debugging-pdo-connection-to-access-database-accdb/

Comment: Mine wasn't that exact situation but that did help solve my issue. I installed the Access Database Engine that was mentioned in that post and now when I select the ACCDB file and use the version that includes both file extensions my connection succeeds and the data displays. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you need the Access database engine to work with .accdb files.

You can download the database engine 2016 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Make sure you use the x64 version of the engine when using 64-bits PHP, and the 32-bits version for 32-bits PHP.

You need the *Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)* for accdb files, as the name implies. So switch comments on that line.

Note that you can get in trouble with a 32-bits office installation and 64-bits php, and the reverse. So match those.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I thought if had to be something with a driver since it was working for MDB but had never heard of the database engine. It is working and display fine now. Thank you!